# Problem regarding overlapping song?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, avaudioplayer

I am using a AVAudio player to play a song,

I take a song from ipod library,

i play a first song but when select other song from ipod library that both song play simultaneously,

How to stop a first song?

I tried to stop a song

```
- (IBAction)player_stop {

   [theAudio stop];

   theAudio = Nil;

}
```

on button play method i write this code

```
- (IBAction)btn_play {

    [self player_stop];

    [theAudio play];

}
```

How i Do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell the player, not the audio, to stop.

`[self.player stop];`

To start a new audio you can do as follows:

```
[self.player stop];
self.player = nil;
NSError *error;
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
[self.player play];
```

Comment: thanks, but cant get it,what is player? is it object of AVAudio player?